# OnSensorChanged Being Called More Than Intended

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

I'm trying to develop an app that detects a fall and so far the accuracy of a fall is in an acceptable range but the problem is the "OnSensorChanged" gets invoked way too frequently causing the toast to appear on my screen constantly.

I think the problem is that during a free fall, the "OnSensorChanged" keeps on getting called for the duration of the fall (since the values correspond to a fall)  which is whats causing the toast spam on my screen.

A solution i tried is to unregister the listener after a fall so that it only appears once but the problem is that it wont detect a fall again unless i restart the app (because obviously the listener stopped working).

Is there any solution to this issue?
Thanks

```
private void checkFall(SensorEvent xyzValues) {
    float[] values = xyzValues.values;
    double rootSquare = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(values[0],2)+Math.pow(values[1],2)+Math.pow(values[2],2));

        if (rootSquare < 1.5){

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "The Phone Fell!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            sensorManager = null;


        }
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        checkFall(event);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a member boolean variable, `mFallen` that keeps track of when a fall has just occurred. You might also want to define some threshold value to indicate when the phone is back to a normal "standing" state. Try the following:

```
    if (rootSquare < 1.5 && !mFallen){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "The Phone Fell!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        mFallen = true;
    } else if (rootSquare > STANDING_THRESHOLD) {
        mFallen = false;
    }
```

### Better Standing Detection Algorithm

Once the state of mFallen has changed from false to true, the magnitude of the device's acceleration vector (as you've calculated and stored in `rootSquare`) should be very close to 0. This is because when the device is in free-fall (falling all by itself), its acceleration will be that of gravity from the reference frame of a standing person. But in theory, the accelerometer would only be measuring values relative to free-fall, and therefore it would be exactly 0.

Since the acceleration of gravity is approximately 9.81 m/s^2, to detect when the device is not moving again, you'd need to check when the magnitude of acceleration is close to that. This is because while still, the sensor will be detecting the force that is preventing it from falling (canceling the acceleration due to gravity) which are the forces of whatever is keeping it still. The overall magnitude of the accelerations due to these forces must sum up exactly to the magnitude of the acceleration due to gravity in this case.

You could define a constant `GRAVITY` to be `9.81`, and `GRAVITY_THRESHOLD` to be a tolerance value, which you can try setting to `0.1` and then refining later on. Try replacing your code with the following:

```
if (rootSquare < 1.5 && !mFallen){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "The Phone Fell!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    mFallen = true;
} else if (Math.abs(rootSquare - GRAVITY) < GRAVITY_THRESHOLD) {
    mFallen = false;
}
```

Just to emphasize, the standing state here is defined as **only when the device has stopped moving**, so it won't be able to detect when the phone has reached a certain height with respect to the ground.

Please see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values, as it may help you understand the problem better.

Comment: Thanks!! Seems to make sense and should work will try it once i'm home and report back the results :D

Comment: No problem, and I just updated the code for more readability. By the way, make sure that you initialize mFallen to false.

Comment: Sorry for some reason my comment wasnt posted :( .. The problem is i couldnt find a standing threshold (the closest was one that triggered the method 2-3) so what i decided to do is just map the boolean (mFallen)  to a button where clicking it will re-enable fall detection .. So for now, the user has to manually re-enable the fall detection since it will be disabled on the first method call. However your suggestion is still the main idea used so thanks :)

Comment: One more thing, the comment that wasnt posted was me confused on why it was triggering 2-4 times :D

Comment: There's definitely a better way to do it than having to re-enable the listener :)

In fact, you should be seeing `onSensorChanged()` called multiple times, since it's continuously checking for sensor value changes, and some of these may be spikes.

Please see my updated answer for a better standing detection algorithm.

Comment: @Y.M Hey it's been a week now, did my updated answer help?

Comment: Hello sorry for the late response. It certainly did help but i need time to test out different values until i reach the perfect threshold (where the method wont be called more than once)